# scala: value is not a member of ListNode[Int]

Tags: scala

me again, newbie to scala and downvote is welcome if this question is stupid to you...

ok, I have a case class called "ListNode", and below is the error I got:

```
scala> case class ListNode[Int](vl: Int, nt: ListNode[Int] = null) {
     |     def value: Int = vl
     |     def next: ListNode[Int] = nt
     | }
defined class ListNode

scala> var a = ListNode(1)
a: ListNode[Int] = ListNode(1,null)

scala> var b = ListNode(2)
b: ListNode[Int] = ListNode(2,null)

scala> a.next = b
<console>:11: error: value next_= is not a member of ListNode[Int]
       a.next = b
         ^
```

I've read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31255688/scala-value-is-not-a-member-of-int) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24681777/scala-value-is-not-a-member-of-int) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18236825/diagnosing-scala-compile-error-value-to-is-not-a-member-of-int) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18008533/scala-how-to-go-resolve-value-is-not-a-member-of-nothing-error) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25163255/still-have-error-value-copy-is-not-a-member-of-nothing-even-i-filter-nothing-c), but still not really understand what it means...

Why cannot I just set the node next to be another node, just like in Java?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because you're using `def`, which is a function. You might want to define the case class using vars.

The below code will work, but you might want to reconsider the whole idea of mutable case classes.

```
case class ListNode[Int](v1:Int, nt:ListNode[Int]=null) {
  var _nt = nt
  def value: Int = v1
  def next: ListNode[Int] = _nt
  def next_=( newNext:ListNode[Int] ) = { _nt = newNext }
}
scala> val a = ListNode(1,null)
a: ListNode[Int] = ListNode(1,null)

scala> a.next = ListNode(2,null)
a.next: ListNode[Int] = ListNode(2,null)
```

Note that mutating case classes is ideally done via copy:

```
scala> a.copy( v1=500 )
res0: ListNode[Int] = ListNode(500,null)
```

Additionally, if something may be `null` you can consider wrapping it in an `Option`... but I assume this is a "kick-the-tires" code, not a production one :-).

Comment: thanks for the explanation, you are right it's not for production...just playing around...excuse me but here "def next_" what is the underscore? shouldn't overloading just use the same name "next" with no underscore in scala?

Comment: This is Scala's way of creating a property. What's actually happening is that in the expression `foo.next=bar` you invoke `foo`'s method `next_=` with `bar` as a parameter. Which makes a lot of sense when you think about it, except that it's not intuitive after coming from almost any other language... That's the Scala state of things, I think :-)

Comment: Thanks a lot Michael!

Answer (score 2):

I see two problems (there may be more).

1 - Your type parameter should be a parameter not an `Int` specification.

2 - If you're going to reassign the value of `next` then it needs to be a `var`.

```
case class ListNode[T](vl: T, nt: ListNode[T] = null) { 
    val value: T = vl
    var next: ListNode[T] = nt
} 

scala> val a = ListNode(1)
a: ListNode[Int] = ListNode(1,null)

scala> val b = ListNode(2)
b: ListNode[Int] = ListNode(2,null)

scala> a.next = b
a.next: ListNode[Int] = ListNode(2,null)
```

Of course, being a case class, it can be greatly simplified.

```
// this is all you need
case class ListNode[T](value: T, var next: ListNode[T] = null)
```

Answer (score 1):

Case classes in Scala are immutable, which means you can't change their values. In this case, even if you weren't using a case class, `next` is a function (it is defined with `def`) so it does not make sense to attempt to assign a value to it.

As an additional point, it is not good practice to use `null` in Scala. Better to use the Option class. There are several ways to you could alter your code to solve your problem. If you want to use mutable classes, consider the following:

```
class ListNode[Int](value: Int, nt: Option[ListNode[Int]] = None) {
  var next = nt
}

object ListNode {

  def apply(value: Int, nt: Option[ListNode[Int]] = None) = new ListNode[Int](value, nt)
}

var a = ListNode(1)

var b = ListNode(2)

a.next = Some(b)
```